# Add a jason data to an existing sheet js-xlsx

Tags: javascript, json, excel, reactjs, js-xlsx

From the example from js-xlsx, we know that after reading a file, we can add new data into that particular sheet:

```
var XLSX = require('xlsx');
var wb = XLSX.readFile('sheetjs.xlsx');
add_cell_to_sheet(wb.Sheets.SheetJS, "F6", 12345);
XLSX.writeFile('sheetjs-new.xlsx', wb);
```

But how to do if my data is not just a single cell? I have a json data that I would like to add into the file that I read. How to add the json data?

Answer (score 0):

After you readFile, you want to create worksheet by json_to_sheet property.

```
var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonPrep);
```

Then you want to add it to the sheet you want.

```
workbook.Sheets.SheetJS = ws;
```

Then you want to write the file.

```
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'sheetjs.xlsx');
```